# Three.js effect Working on firefox but not working on chrome

Tags: javascript, arrays, three.js

I implemented recursively search the adjacent faces using Half Edge data structure and color them accordingly. However, I can see the effect on the firefox but not on chrome. Does anyone have an idea? Help would be appreciated!

```
 function neighbor(color_indices){
    var color_indices_length = color_indices.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < color_indices_length; i++) {
        var adjacentFaces = heData.findAdjacentFacesToFace(color_indices[i]);
        for (var k = 0; k < 3; k++){
            if(color_indices.indexOf(adjacentFaces[k]) == -1) {
                color_indices.push(adjacentFaces[k]);
            }
        }
    }
}

function recursion(recursion_times, color_indices){
        for (var z = 1; z <= recursion_times; z++){
            neighbor(color_indices)
        }
}

function red() {
        gl_object.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
        for(var j=0; j < red_indices.length; j++){
            gl_object.children[0].geometry.faces[red_indices[j]].color = new THREE.Color(0xff0000);
        }
}

function red_color() {  
        red_indices.push(selectedFaces[0].faceIndex);
        recursion(11,red_indices);
        red();
}
```

Also, I tried this implementation, too! but has the same effect (not working on my chrome)

```
//test
    var adjacentFaces = [];
    var temp = [];
    temp[0] = heData.findAdjacentFacesToFace(color_indices[i])[0];
    temp[1] = heData.findAdjacentFacesToFace(color_indices[i])[1];
    temp[2] = heData.findAdjacentFacesToFace(color_indices[i])[2];

    adjacentFaces.push(temp[0]);
    adjacentFaces.push(temp[1]);
    adjacentFaces.push(temp[2]);
```

Comment: link to the page - http://jangheei.com/KIST/bunny+3.html; let me know if you browser doesn't support red coloring effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was the simple matter just change

```
  for (var k = 0; k < 3; k++){
        if(color_indices.indexOf(adjacentFaces[k]) == -1) {
            color_indices.push(adjacentFaces[k]);
        }
    }
```

to

```
  for (var k = 0; k < adjacentFaces.length; k++){
        if(color_indices.indexOf(adjacentFaces[k]) == -1) {
            color_indices.push(adjacentFaces[k]);
        }
    }
```